# I warped an image in opencv using warpPerspective, but now I want to match coordinates of the original image to coors in the new warped image. How?

Tags: python, opencv

I used an aruco marker and its four corners to warp an image in OPENCV (PYTHON) using:

```
      matrix = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(pts1, pts2)
      print('warp matrix', matrix)
      result2 = cv2.warpPerspective(image_original, matrix, (resolution[0], resolution[1]))
```

But on the warped image, I can no longer identify the corners of the aruco marker using:

```
arucoDict = cv2.aruco.Dictionary_get(cv2.aruco.DICT_6X6_50)
arucoParams = cv2.aruco.DetectorParameters_create()
(corners, ids, rejected) = cv2.aruco.detectMarkers(image, arucoDict,
                                                   parameters=arucoParams)
```

No corners are found on the warped image. I assume this is because the warp 'destroyed' my aruco's proportions. Would be awesome if someone knew why this is.

But my main issue: I would like to know the coordinates of the 4 aruco marker corners in the warped image. I know the coordinates on the original image and I have the matrix i used to warp. How do I do this?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried printing the coordinates of points in `pts2`?

Comment: I wont lie to you, I feel pretty dumb right about now for missing such an obvious thing...  Thank you, sometimes it really takes someone looking at the problem from a distance.


I still wonder how one would convert other points, and why the Aruco was not recognised after warping, but this is obviously the solution to my immediate problem. 


THANK YOU!!!!

Comment: You can use: `cv2.transform` to transform any point using a transformation matrix

Answer (score 0):

As perfectly pointed out by @Baraa in the comments, you can access the coordinates in the `pts2` variable. Also you can use `cv2.transform` to transform any unknown point using a transformation matrix. You can see a few example here: [Python cv2.transform() Examples](https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/110702/cv2.transform)

Comment: So your ‘answer’ is that Baraa answered the question? So, this isn’t the answer.

Comment: @barny Actually, it's quite common to see other users transfer answers given in comments to the answer section, as comments are temporary and won't guarantee to remain when someone else encounters the same problem and finds this question.

Comment: @AnnZen thanks for posting. Yes, this is true and I appreciate you marking this as an actual answer. I do not know why it was downvoted, as you gave credit where due and my problem is solved and I am happy, 

But if you are going to mark it as an answer, please also specify that 'You can use: cv2.transform to transform any unknown point using a transformation matrix'.

Comment: @Ruben Thanks. I've added that part too.